# Updating Openssl in os x yosemite

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, macports

```
-- Build of crashreporter disabled.
-- Found Qt5 core, checking for further dependencies...
-- Using Qt 5!
-- GIT_SHA1 40cdbda31285d9090d8109b10b244aa4740a5891
-- Using Qt 5.4.x
-- We would not require Neon in this setup, compile without!
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "0.9.8zc", but
required is at least "1.0.0" (found
/usr/lib/libssl.dylib;/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:372 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.1.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:318  (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:146 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Tried to install the openssl latest version 1.0.2 using "brew" and also using "mac ports" but still no luck.

Also tried to give the path as prefix to "cmake" **FAILED**

Replacing the dylib of "openssl" and "libcrypto" with latest version and making aliases of them **FAILED**

So anyone have a solution???
I'm trying to build 
https://github.com/owncloud/client

Comment: This is a build problem of a software, which is development-related, so I think it's right here. Note that "Replacing the dylib of "openssl" and "libcrypto" with latest version and making aliases of them" is a BAAAAAAD idea. /usr/lib is Apple-land and you should *never* *ever* modify it manually. You might have broken your system. (Fortunately, not a lot of Apple things still use OpenSSL, but that's just luck). Note that you also shouldn't mix brew and MacPorts -- that's asking for disaster. To fix your problem you need to add the correct paths to include and library search paths.

Comment: Hi @Hamdullah shah, i have same problem. Do you find some soluton to update this libs?: P

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So i solve the problem,  i was using http://ohmyz.sh and updating "PATH" in zsh is a mess.
After uninstalling the zsh and reinstalling everything with "brew" solve the problem.
Everything works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 8):

Why not take the advice cmake gives you? Before running cmake, run `export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$(brew --prefix openssl)` in the same terminal session.

Comment: tried and the variable is also added to "env" but still no luck OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2